# Form reloads the page but does not submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on Asp.net MVC Application. When I use a form and try to submit , it just reloads the page. I have included the method and Action info , but the form and data are not sent to address specified in action attribute of form. Any help please

```
<form action="/Search/SearchforQuery/" method="post" runat="server"> 
   <p>Search : <input style="font-size:medium; width: 600px; height: 29px;" 
       name="searchField" id="searchField" /></p> 
 </div> <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" /> 
 </form>
```

Comment: can you post some code so we can investigate your issue?

Comment: So how am I going to send data to controller from an asp.net page. I have some textfields and I want to send the data from fields to server or controller action. I hope this helps

Comment: You are going to need to post an example Waheed. Can you copy the form markup from the View you are having trouble with perhaps?

Comment: <form action="/Search/SearchforQuery/" method="post" runat="server">
 <p>Search : 
            <input style="font-size:medium; width: 600px; height: 29px;" name="searchField" id="searchField" 
                /></p>
           </div>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
       
        </form>

Comment: This is the code .. I have a controller Search with Action SearchforQuery I want to send data in the input field searchField to server. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using **runat="server"** if you are using MVC?

Delete it.
Try to use:

```
 @{ using (Html.BeginForm(...))
 {
  <p>
  Content here
  </p>
 }
```

Comment: +1 - exactly what i was thinking and was literally about to add. also, there's a 'weird' stray </div> inside the example OP code (plus a few horrid inline styles), so quite a few basics to be addressed way ahead of any mvc advice i feel